# PHP preg_match returning null

Tags: php, regex

A customer reported a bug and I've traced it to this code, but I can't figure out what is wrong with it:

```
$source = "This is a test.\n\n-- a <span style='color:red'>red word</span>!\n\n- a red word!\n\n";
//$find = "- a red word!";  // This one works!
$find = "- a <span style='color:red'>red word</span>!";  // This one doesn't...
$replace = "&bull; a <span style='color:red'>red word</span>!";
$pattern = '/^' . preg_quote($find) . '$/';
$results = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $source);
die ("Results: " . serialize($results));
```

I've included a sample of a `$find` that works vs a `$find` that doesn't work. Any idea why the uncommented `$find` doesn't work?

(Note: I'm not actually trying to parse HTML and the search is purely a sample, so I don't need corrections on the approach)

Comment: Please use properly [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php), you **must** define the delimiter you're using, else the default value is `NULL`, so try `$pattern = '/^' . preg_quote($find, '/') . '$/';`. Also if you have turned on error reporting or checked the logs, you should have noticed something.

Comment: Why not use `str_replace` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_quote` doesn't escape the slash character found in `</span>` which makes the pattern invalid. `preg_quote` does permit defining the delimiter for the pattern:

```
$pattern = '/^' . preg_quote($find, '/') . '$/';
```

Comment: True, I just saw that.

Answer (score 1):

You must remove anchors (`^` `$`) since what you try to match is only a substring, not all the string.

```
$pattern = '~' . preg_quote($find) . '~';
```

Answer (score 1):

`preg_quote` escapes only special regular expression characters which are: `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`. Because the forward slash is not a regexp special character, you must use  a different delimiter, say colon sign `|`, in your pattern like this

```
$pattern = '/' . preg_quote($find) . '/';
```

or provide your back slash delimiter to the `preg_quote` function as a second parameter like this

```
$pattern = '/' . preg_quote($find, '/') . '$/';
```

[From the PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) on the `preg_quote` function (description of the second parameter):

```
If the optional delimiter is specified, it will also be escaped. This is useful for escaping the delimiter that is required by the PCRE functions. The / is the most commonly used delimiter.
```

And get rid of `^` and `$`, as was already suggested - you are not matching the whole string.